# Tokenize stringstream based on type

Tags: c++, iostream, sstream

I have an input stream containing integers and special meaning characters '#'. It looks as follows:
`... 12 18 16 # 22 24 26 15 # 17 # 32 35 33 ...`
The tokens are separated by space. There's no pattern for the position of '#'.

I was trying to tokenize the input stream like this:

```
int value;
std::ifstream input("data");
if (input.good()) {
  string line;
  while(getline(data, line) != EOF) {
    if (!line.empty()) {
      sstream ss(line);
      while (ss >> value) {
        //process value ...

      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem with this code is that the processing stops when the first '#' is encountered.

The only solution I can think of is to extract each individual token into a string (not '#') and use atoi() function to convert the string to an integer. However, it's very inefficient as the majority tokens are integer. Calling atoi() on the tokens introduces big overhead.

Is there a way I can parse the individual token by its type? ie, for integers, parse it as integers while for '#', skip it. Thanks!

Comment: is using getline twice acccepable? if so use `getline( data, line, '#');` fisrt.

Comment: @ahenderson I didn't get your point. One of the function signatures of getline is: istream& getline ( istream& is, string& str, char delim ); By passing '#' as the third argument to getline, getline() will take '#' as delimitor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility would be to explicitly skip whitespace (`ss >> std::ws`), and then to use `ss.peek()` to find out if a `#` follows. If yes, use `ss.get()` to read it and continue, otherwise use `ss >> value` to read the value.

If the positions of `#` don't matter, you could also remove all `'#'` from the line before initializing the `stringstream` with it.

Comment: Thanks. Your solution always looks ahead, for '#', use ss.get() to consume it and keep going. If the '#' can be other non-numeric characters, can we have a more general solution?

Comment: @itnovice: If your numbers are all positive integers (i.e. composed only of the digits `0` to `9`), you can just pass it to `isdigit`. If it is a digit, you can proceed to read the value, otherwise you know it's a non-numeric character. Alternatively you can use the test `next < '0' || next > '9'` (where `next` contains the result of `peek`) to identify non-digits.

Answer (score 2):

Usually not worth testing against good()

```
if (input.good()) {
```

Unless your next operation is generating an error message or exception. If it is not good all further operations will fail anyway.

Don't test against `EOF`.

while(getline(data, line) != EOF) {

The result of std::getline() is not an integer. It is a reference to the input stream. The input stream is convertible to a bool like object that can be used in bool a context (like `while` `if` etc..). So what you want to do:

```
while(getline(data, line)) {
```

I am not sure I would read a line. You could just read a word (since the input is space separated). Using the >> operator on string

```
std::string word;
while(data >> word) {  // reads one space separated word
```

Now you can test the word to see if it is your special character:

```
if (word[0] == "#")
```

If not convert the word into a number.

This is what I would do:

```
// define a class that will read either value from a stream
class MyValue
{
  public:
    bool isSpec() const {return isSpecial;}
    int  value()  const {return intValue;}

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream, MyValue& data)
    {
        std::string item;
        stream >> item;
        if (item[0] == '#') {
            data.isSpecial = true;
        } else
        {   data.isSpecial = false;
            data.intValue  = atoi(&item[0]);
        }
        return stream;
    }
  private:
    bool isSpecial;
    int  intValue;
};

// Now your loop becomes:
MyValue  val;
while(file >> val)
{
    if (val.isSpec())  { /* Special processing */ }
    else               { /* We have an integer */ }
}
```

Comment: Your solution is very nice. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can read all values as std::string and then check if it's "#" or not (and if not - convert to int)

Answer (score 1):

```
int value;
std::ifstream input("data");
if (input.good()) {
    string line;
    std::sstream ss(std::stringstream::in | std::stringstream::out);
    std::sstream ss2(std::stringstream::in | std::stringstream::out);
    while(getline(data, line, '#') {
        ss << line;
        while(getline(ss, line, ' ') {
            ss2 << line;
            ss2 >> value
            //process values ...
            ss2.str("");  
        }
        ss.str("");
    }
}
```

In here we first split the line by the token '#' in the first while loop then in the second while loop we split the line by ' '.

Comment: I don't have a c++ compiler on this machine o the code is not test. So use this as a general outline of how it should work.

Comment: @itnovice small error i had `ss >> value` that should be ss2 >> value

Answer (score 0):

Personally, if your separator is *always* going to be space regardless of what follows, I'd recommend you just take the input as string and parse from there. That way, you can take the string, see if it's a number or a # and whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should re-examine your premise that "Calling atoi() on the tokens introduces big overhead-"

There is no magic to `std::cin >> val`. Under the hood, it ends up calling (something very similar to) atoi.

If your tokens are huge, there might be some overhead to creating a `std::string` but as you say, the vast majority are numbers (and the rest are #'s) so they should mostly be short.

Comment: I wasn't aware that std::cin >> val ends up calling some function that is similar to atoi(). So my assumption was wrong. Thanks for pointing this out.